# section loop value at the smarty

Tags: smarty

I've got some issue with drop down menu, I am using smarty template.
The default one is using drop down menu from 1-25.
And I would like to know if I can change it 5000, 10000, 15000,...

```
    <select id="mychoice" name="mychoice1" style="width:100px;" class="choicebox">{section name=i start=1 loop=26}
    <option value="{$smarty.section.i.index}" 
        {if $mychoice1 eq $smarty.section.i.index}selected{/if}>{$smarty.section.i.index}
    </option>
    {/section}
    </select>
```

And I changed the line above as below.

```
{section name=i start=5000 loop=26 step=5000}
```

But it doesnt work. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{section name=i start=5000 loop=26 step=5000}

This is wrong syntax start value will be the start point for looping and loop will be the till end of the loop

so,

your code is correct why you have using the secode code ?
If you want to change you should do something like this:

```
{section name=i start=5000 loop=5026}
{section name=i start=10000 loop=10026}
{section name=i start=15000 loop=15026}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I misunderstood the meaning of 'loop'. Anyway Correct answer what I wanted was...   {section name=i start=5000 loop=5005000 step=5000}.